# calling R from python using rpy2

Tags: python, r, exe, rpy2

I am trying to shift from `R` to `Python` for big data analytics. But since I still need some of the excellent statistical functions present in R, I invoke them  in `Python` using `rpy2`.

My question is does `rpy2` has any limitation regarding calling R functions. And can we convert a python script into an executable file , when we are using R inside python ?

Also can we call custom functions from `R` to `Python` using the same library?

Comment: These are two different questions. Have you tried something out?

Comment: @User, I have been using `rpy2` for quite a time, till now I have not faced any roadblock. But I have never converted any python scripts into executable files. So I was looking out for someone with experience in this matter